# Go chi middleware to add item to response header

Tags: go, go-chi

My concept is simple, I would like to add the request ID (generated by chi `middleware.RequestID` to the response header).

My code below adds `X-Request-Id` but does not add the ID itself. I am not sure why, since surely it is available in the context because `middleware.RequestID` is higher up in the middleware chain ?

My router creation:

```
package rest

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware"
    "goWebAPI/pkg/database"
    "goWebAPI/pkg/rest/mw"
    "goWebAPI/pkg/rest/routes"
)

func GetRouter(db *database.Database) *chi.Mux {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(mw.SendRequestID)
    r.Use(middleware.RealIP)
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
    r.Use(middleware.Timeout(60 * time.Second))
    r.Get("/", routes.IndexRoute())
    return r
}
```

My custom middleware:

```
package mw

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware"
)

const requestIDHeader = "X-Request-Id"

func SendRequestID(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        if w.Header().Get(requestIDHeader) == "" {
            w.Header().Add(
                requestIDHeader,
                middleware.GetReqID(context.Background()),
            )
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(fn)
}
```

My Index Route:

```
package routes

import "net/http"

func IndexRoute() http.HandlerFunc {
    fn:= func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("welcome"))
    }
    return fn
}
```

Comment: Base on your description, `middleware.GetReqID` is returning empty string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your issue is here:

```
middleware.GetReqID(context.Background())
```

This tries to get the request ID of a new, empty context, but you need the request ID for the current request, meaning it *should* be:

```
middleware.GetReqID(r.Context())
```

(Or, since you're already grabbing the request context in local `ctx`, you could also use that.)

This is [documented in `GetReqId`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware#GetReqID) (emphasis mine):

> GetReqID returns a request ID **from the given context** if one is present. Returns the empty string if a request ID cannot be found.